# Fermentable sugars in Vanilla

Tags: fermentation, sugar

I am a big fan of Dogfish Head's use of natural sugars in fermentation.  I recall an apricot IPA that really blew my mind.  The fruit came through in a unique way that wasn't too sweet.

I was considering what else could be used like this.

Do real vanilla beans contain any fermentable sugars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually only 2-3 vanilla beans are scraped and added to secondary for a really good amount of flavor In a 5 gallon batch.

No, in those amounts there is very little fermentables in the vanilla beans.

Comment: What do you think about soaking them in vodka first?  Is that a must to mitigate any risk of contamination?

Comment: @rbreier yep a tincture is common if concerned. Use as little vodka as possible and make sure the beans are cut and scraped going into the tincture.